# Bcc in email not working in Yii framework

Tags: php, email, yii

I want to send copy of mail to given mail address (Bcc), but it's not sending copy of it (Bcc) not working however mail sent successfully.

I am using Yii framework and code something like

```
$email = Yii::app()->email;

$email->to = $modelVar->user->email;

$email->subject = 'Registration Confirmation';

$email->bcc= 'to-admin@gmail.com'; // Not working

$email->view = 'reg-view-here';

$email->viewVars = array('vars' => $modelVar);

$email->send();
```

Comment: Which version of Yii which extensions used?

Comment: The [Yii 2.0 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html#basic-usage) shows an entirely different syntax :-?

Comment: I've seen phpmailer and swiftmailer examples.  That's why it's good to know versions and extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Yii is using phpmailer then try:

```
<?php
$mailer->addBCC('foo@example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks. Working now